# How to check multiple statements?

Tags: java, android

In my quiz game on the very end of a level I have to check some conditions, 4 of them. During the game I add +1 to an integer variable, 4 variables. On the end of the level I sum these values to another integer, activeButtonsTotal. And I set 4 boolean values to true or false. So, I need to check 2 conditions four times: if it's my boolean is false AND if my activeButtonsTotal is equal to 16 and if it is to set one of my buttons to Enabled, and this same thing for the next boolean and activeButtonsTotal, and 4 times like this. I need to go through all 4 of them. I tried with if statements, and else if but no luck.

```
boolean columnACorrecct, columnBCorrect, columnCCorrect, columnDCorrect;

activeButtonsTotal = activeButtonsA+activeButtonsB+activeButtonsC+activeButtonsD;

if((columnACorrect=false) && (activeButtonsTotal==16)){
columnA.setEnabled(true);
}
    if((columnBCorrect=false) && (activeButtonsTotal==16)){
    columnB.setEnabled(true);
    }
       if((columnCCorrect=false) && (activeButtonsTotal==16)){
       columnC.setEnabled(true);
       }
            if((columnDCorrect=false) && (activeButtonsTotal==16)){
            columnD.setEnabled(true);
            }
```

Comment: Which input values give you unsatisfactory results, and how do those results differ from what you want?

Answer (score 4):

im not sure that i follow all your logic, but your "if" statements all are missing an equal sign. You said you have to compare if your boolean is false, AND the number, but you are assigning "False" inside the condition. you need "==".

I would do:

```
if(activeButtonsTotal==16)
{
    columnA.setEnabled(!columnACorrect);
    columnB.setEnabled(!columnBCorrect);
    columnC.setEnabled(!columnCCorrect);
    columnD.setEnabled(!columnDCorrect);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like that:

```
columnA.setEnabled(!columnACorrect && activeButtonsTotal==16);
columnB.setEnabled(!columnBCorrect && activeButtonsTotal==16);
columnC.setEnabled(!columnCCorrect && activeButtonsTotal==16);
columnD.setEnabled(!columnDCorrect && activeButtonsTotal==16);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning your boolean variable to false every time you try to check a condition.
This will result in the condition to be false and will never run the code within the block.

To check for equality, use ==;

```
columnACorrect==false
columnBCorrect==false
columnCCorrect==false
columnDCorrect==false
```

But I would recommend using:

```
!columnACorrect
!columnBCorrect
!columnCCorrect
!columnDCorrect
```

It does the same thing. The 2nd option is more preferable.

Comment: That was it. A simple mistake. One = was missing, I overlooked it. Thanks